# Show edit link in revision list for users without full edit privilege

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, revisions-list

Users with full edit privileges see edit links in the list of revisions for a post:

> [image: screenshot]

However, these aren't shown for users without that privilege even though they can suggest edits:

> [image: screenshot]

Can you please add "edit" link that will act as a shortcut to suggest an edit based on the specific revision?